# Lazy Collection in Java

Tags: java, collections

Consider a problem, in which I'm developing a tree like Collection.

One of the main functionality of my Collection is to trace all the stored items one by one and then call a **given function** for each item until a **given criteria** has been met (lazy Collection).

So the function should have the following signatures:

```
void Trace(function func, criteria crit)
{
    item i = firstItem();
    while (i != endItem())
    {
        i = nextItem();
        func(i);
        if (crit(i))
            return;
    }
}
```

in `C++` function pointers can be used for `func` and `crit`.
in `C#`, `yield` keyword is exactly the solution to this problem, I believe.

How can I get the same thing in Java?

Comment: Your loop has s bug. It doesn't process the last element. Consider a list if length 1 - the while loop would not be entered.

Comment: Good Point :)
But fortunately, that has not much to do with the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you would pass references to objects of classes that implement applicable functions, or use Commons Collections instead:

- Use [`Predicate`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Predicate.html) implementations for the `crit` part.
- Use [`Closure`](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/Closure.html) implementations for the `func` part.

For example:

```
Closure c = new Closure() {
    public void execute(Object obj) {
        ...
    }
};

Predicate p = new Predicate() {
    public boolean evaluate(Object obj) {
        ...
    }
}

Trace(c, p);
```

Comment: +1, and if you prefer to stick with core Java, [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) provides a reasonable generic interface for closure-like things that can return a value.

Comment: @RyanStewart, my problem with `Callable` is that it doesn't provide the API that the OP wanted. The `call()` method receives no parameters, which means that you'd have to create a new instance of your `Callable` implementation with each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for here is the [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) design pattern.

The goal of this pattern to to abstract the implementation of an algorithm into a Strategy object. Here, your algorithms are the `func` and `crit` functions that you're looking to pass in.

So, you'd have an interface called something like `TraceStrategy`. You'd then pass implementations of this interface in to your collection. Your code would then look something like

```
void Trace(TraceStrategy traceStrategy)
{
    item i = firstItem();
    while (i != endItem())
    {
        i = nextItem();
        traceStrategy.func(i);
        if (traceStrategy.crit(i))
            return;
    }
}
```

and

```
interface TraceStrategy {
   public boolean crit(item i);

   public void func(item i);
}
```

You'd probably want to make this generic, so that you weren't tied to `item`... but you get the idea.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that there will always be a coupling between `crit` and `func`. If you have `x` possibilities for `crit` and `y` possibilities for `func`, you might end up creating `x*y` implementations of `TraceStrategy`... therefore, parameterization is a slightly better approach IMO.

Comment: @Isaac, excellent point. You could create a `TraceStrategyFactory` that takes `CritStrategy` and `FuncStrategy` objects and returns a composite object composed of those two... but your point about coupling these two function is very apropos

Comment: Yes. I agree that a combination of strategy pattern & parameterization would be the best fit for the OP's needs overall.

Answer (score 1):

Create an interface that declares the methods, and require a reference to an object implementing the interface as argument. The caller can create the object using an anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this `trace` function work just fine in Java by combining a couple of techniques:

- Instead of "function pointers", your parameters `func` and `crit` should be object instances that implement a specific interface. You can then call a function in this interface on the object `i`. In effect, this is a Vistor Pattern with two different vistor parameters.
- You also need some way to traverse the tree. You could implement an `Iterator` - this gives you a nice way to traverse the entire structure. Alternatively you could make `trace` recursive (it calls itself on left and right branches of the tree) and then you wouldn't need an iterator.

The iterator version would look something like this:

```
public void trace(IFunction func, ICriteria crit) {
    for (T i: this) {
        func.call(i);
        if (crit.test(i)) return;
    }
}
```

Here `T` is the item type of the collection, and `call` and `test` are the function definitions in the `IFunction` and `ICriteria` interfaces respectively.